# rails restful routing - single index with nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm working on a rails application which is built around a tree data structure. As such, the index of the controller displays the root node of said structure. Demonstration is probably easier to explain what I want:

```
/place/1 == place
```

can I restfully define such that

```
/place/1/photos == place/photos
```

and

```
/place/1/photos/1 == place/photos/1
```

etc?

Ideally what I'd like is that the articles url and its nested resource urls work by default such that I don't need to change a whole bunch of stuff and conditionally generate paths all over the place.

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the usual nested restful routes (it's good to keep them as the baseline, and to use them for the non-sexy urls like update, create, etc) and then add some custom routes for your 'pretty' urls:

```
map.nested_photo "/place/photos/:id", :controller => "photos", :action => "show"
map.edit_nested_photo "/place/photos/:id/edit", :controller => "photos", :action => "edit"
```

you could then add a bit of logic into the photos controller to make sure you have the place even if you didn't get params[:place_id], eg

```
  if params[:place_id]
    @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
  else 
    @place = @photo.place
  end
```

The main thing to watch out for in custom urls is that you don't create any conflict with a) the regular restful urls or b) your other custom urls.